# Get JSON url from selecting an image or button to string in Swift 4

Tags: json, iphone, swift, parsing, swift4

Hello Stack Overflow community.

I'm currently working at the interface of my new app.
As I'm trying to fetch some JSON data from a web server I have a little issue(don't know what should I do) while implementing it to the app.

Basically what I'm trying to get is an Button or Image when selected gets me a selection in my JSON Url

Example with fruits:

[image: Select FRUIT]

1. I selected banana an will get this JSON url:

   `"https://www.examplewithfruits.com/getsomeFruit"+"banana"+"fromList"`
2. I selected apple an will get this JSON url:

   `"https://www.examplewithfruits.com/getsomeFruit"+"apple"+"fromList"`

It's important that the person doesn't need to write the word down in a box rather to select an image or button. After selecting some of the images an new activity will be loaded on a new page. Also is it possible to combine the image and a text box?(to write for example an username down)

Sorry if the question is stupid but I really don't know what would be the best way to solve this. Would appreciate for some examples or links.
Thanks!

Comment: You are using UItableView didSelectRow method, select banana row you  will get JSON url

Comment: you could use the didSelectRow method , then determine what row did you just select and then select one of 2 strings that are saved in and var or an array to display them  , to determine what row you selected check its row number for example if use select banana and banana was the 2nd element then the row number should be ... and so on try to debug it to understand more about the (index.row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    var imageArray =["Banana","Apple"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additioa lf
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageArray[indexPath.row])
        return Cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // Your Json url

        var url = "https://www.examplewithfruits.com/getsomeFruit"+"\(self.imageArray[indexpath.row])"+"fromList"
    }
}
```